# How do I open and use another android app through my own after a certain event?

Tags: android, input, automation, sms, cross-application

I'm looking to do the following, but have no idea where to start, I have some basic android understanding and hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have an app.  That app waits for an SMS from a certain number.  As I understand it's not so hard to accomplish using the `content://sms/inbox` content resolver.
(this is as far I can manage on my own)

Upon receiving such an SMS I want to open another app (not mine) and press a certain button (or even navigate the UI until i get to it).

Is this possible to achieve? If yes, how?

I don't care how to, it can be a classy solution using libraries meant for it, or it could be brute force "record the touch input", but I really have no idea where to start in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app you want to launch must have certain intents that you can invoke form you app when you recieve the SMS

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.thirdparty.package");
startActivity( intent );
```

Comment: that solves the ability to start the target app, thanks you, but i still need to emulate a button press\screen navigation inside that app

Comment: Which app do you want to open. Apps do not support custom actions. Suppose there is a submit button in an application you cannot make it do other activities

Comment: But certain apps such as the camera supports startActivityForResult which opens the camera clicks the picture and returns the clicked image to the users activity

Comment: so there's no way to simulate user input to use another app? i was thinking in the worst case, if could just feed it even x and y values for where a "touch" should happen, it would be great